# converting text file data to excel using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to convert a text file data to excel, below is the content of the text file:

ModuleName FailedCount SucceededCount TotalCount

BESS                0            80         80

IG                 0             14         14

the spaces between the words in the the text file are not fixed, so i how do i convert this data to excel? I tried the solution given in below URL, but it is not working.

https://tecgang.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/text-2-excel/

Comment: Excel's `Data` -> `Text to columns` .

Comment: import your txt file, then replace the space with comma using  -replace ' ',','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert that file into a CSV file:

```
$rawData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\theFile.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}

# this gets the list separator character your local Excel expects when double-clicking a CSV file
$delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
($rawData -replace '\s+', $delimiter) | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\theNewFile.csv'
```

Now you have a CSV file you can double-click to open in Excel

[image]